# Logrotate with rotate commented

Tags: linux, logrotate

I have logrotate config and I have commented the rotate but the files are rotated 10 times in the below manner

```
testlog.log
testlog.log.1
testlog.log.2
........
testlog.log.10
```

Configuration used for logrotate is

```
    /var/log/test/*.log{
     size 250M
    # rotate 10
     missingok
     dateext
     copytruncate
     delaycompress
     compress
     notifycompress
     olddir /var/log/test/archive 
}
```

Even though rotate is commented why the rotate is happening?  Am new to this log rotation using for the 1st time and also I need to increase the rotation to keep the log for at least 1 month

Comment: There should be a `logrotate.conf` file that applies a common set of options to all `logrotate` calls. It is usually found at `/etc/logrotate.conf`. Check that file for any unwanted rotation options.

Comment: @parttimeturtle I have default conf of weekly
rotate 4
create
dateext
#compress